# How to update models in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How to update models in ASP.NET CORE if you have added tables or modified them in the database. I used it to create models. I found it on the Internet about the migration but it did not work. It did not work to overwrite the files either.

Comment: Migrations update the database from models, not the other way around. It sounds like you want to use the database-first approach instead of code-first.

Comment: The documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli does work. I'd suggest you go through these steps again and write down the steps as you do them. If things still don't work for you post the steps here and we can see what you are missing.

Comment: How you added the tables? Can you show us the code?

Comment: yes, I want to update the models from the database. That is to change tables in SQL server and update the models in asp.net core

Answer (score 0):

In the Nuget Shell you need to change directory to your project (`cd projectname/`) and then you can

`Add-Migration GoodNameOfYourChanges` and

`Update-Database`